# How can I trim two mutable String in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I am facing a problem with trimming NSMutableString. Specifically, I can't find information about trimming two mutable strings. I am doing something like this.

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if(!myMutableString1Obj)
        myMutableString1Obj = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
    {
        [myMutableString1Obj appendString:string];

        NSString *trimmedString1 = [myMutableString1Obj stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
        [myMutableString1Obj setString:trimmedString1];

        NSData *data1 = [myMutableString1Obj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        response1dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data1 options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",response1dict);


    }

    if(!myMutableStringObj)
        myMutableStringObj = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
    {
        [myMutableStringObj appendString:string];

        NSString *trimmedString = [myMutableStringObj stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
        [myMutableStringObj setString:trimmedString];

        NSData *datasite = [myMutableStringObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        responsedict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:datasite options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responsedict);


    }


        myMutableString2Obj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
        NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableString2Obj);
        NSData *data = [myMutableString2Obj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        response2dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",response2dict);
}
```

Here I am using XML data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code:

```
[myMutableString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]
```

this will trim your string and remove new line and whitespaces

Comment: That I am already using but that is good when there is only one string

Comment: But you append all the string to the namutablestring before and then call this function

Comment: I have used your code but now my foundcharector is no call